# Sql union query for same column in same table with different where conditions

Tags: sql, union

I need Amount and CarAmount in two different columns for bi publisher report.Here same column PROJECT_COST is used with different conditions.But union only returns result from first part of union.

```
select     
peia.PROJECT_COST as Amount,
Null CarAmount

from    
Project_Element ppet,
Project_Items peia,
Project_Types petb

where   
peia.TASK_ID=ppet.PROJ_ELEMENT_ID
and  petb.ATTRIBUTE1 in (51110, 51170, 59999)

UNION
select     
peia. PROJECT_COST as CarAmount,
Null  Amount

from    
Project_Element ppet,
Project_Items peia,
Project_Types petb

where   
peia.TASK_ID=ppet.PROJ_ELEMENT_ID
and  petb.ATTRIBUTE1 in (59500)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing *not* to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Hi I am using this query to build datamodel for BI publisher report. I have to use this peia. PROJECT_COST column for various cost amount depending on the conditions.I was told to use Union ,but I am getting only first part of result returned

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` ignores your aliases in the second query. It will simply map the first column to the first column and the second to the second. Instead of renaming the columns, try to reorder them.

I need Amount and CarAmount in two different columns for bi publisher report.Here same column PROJECT_COST is used with different conditions.But union only returns result from first part of union.

```
select
peia.PROJECT_COST as Amount, Null CarAmount

from
Project_Element ppet, Project_Items peia, Project_Types petb

where
peia.TASK_ID=ppet.PROJ_ELEMENT_ID and petb.ATTRIBUTE1 in (51110, 51170, 59999)

UNION select
Null Amount, peia.PROJECT_COST as CarAmount

from
Project_Element ppet, Project_Items peia, Project_Types petb

where
peia.TASK_ID=ppet.PROJ_ELEMENT_ID and petb.ATTRIBUTE1 in (59500)
```

Additionally, I would suggest to use `UNION ALL`. `UNION` suffers a performance hit due to the fact that it will return only distinct values. Since you are filtering on different ID's and putting data in different columns, SQL Server doesn't have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much Menno, i tried with changing order of the column and union all...but still I am getting the only result from first part of the query...please help

Comment: @newbee Have you tried executing just the second part of the query? Does it give you the expected result?

Comment: yes it has result when I run both queries separately...but when I do union all only first part  result I am getting

Comment: Can you show me a query with union like the same scenario where you can see the result as expected